# Is it bad practice to split a C array by simply using a pointer to the middle of it?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I am implementing a version of merge sort in c.  For the first step I have to split the array into sub-arrays.

Is it bad practice to simply do this by having two pointers, one pointing to the start of the original array and the second pointing to the middle?

Or should I malloc 2 new memory slots, copy the appropriate values here and then keep a pointer to this space?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think it's bad practice if you know what you're doing. In some cases, you sacrifice readability for efficiency. It's probably more clear if you'd just create two more arrays, but if you have a firm grasp on arrays and pointers, why allocate extra memory?

Comment: On the other hand, doing anything in C if you don't know what you're doing is bad practice.

Comment: @WilliamPursell :) unless you use `printf` without variadic parameters. That one's pretty easy.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, you mean `printf("%s\n");`?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, I understood that you said `printf` without variadic parameters is something you can get right, even without knowing what you're doing. So I gave a counter-example.

Answer (score 11):

Absolutely not! The whole point of programming in C is being able to do these neat pointer tricks!

Do note, however, that mergesort is not inplace so you will still need to malloc an auxiliary array. If you do the correct pointer tricks you can just malloc once and reuse it though.

Answer (score 2):

It's just fine to use one array in such case (as merge sort). Calling malloc is unnecessary, unless the size of the array is too big for the stack.

Answer (score 2):

Generally with merge sort you want to put the result of the merge into the memory occupied by the original input. If so, then you should:

- sort both halves
- copy the "lower" half of your array into a newly-allocated buffer, leave the "upper" half where it is
- merge from the "upper" half and the extra buffer, into the "bottom" of the big array.

That way, you only need to allocate as much extra memory as *half* the size of the input. You could even do that once at the start, and re-use the same buffer as working space for all the merges that you're going to do.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not bad, and in fact I would argue that this is one of the only reasons for using C in the first place. If you're going to make wasteful copies of your data every time you need to treat the same data slightly differently, you've already invoked one of the biggest costs of high level script languages. You've also drastically increased the amount of error handling your code must do (since the allocation can fail), and since error handling in C tends to be a bit "verbose" (putting it kindly), the net complexity cost is much worse than the slight complexity cost of accessing a subarray in-place.